# Use type assertion in Angular and rxjs map function

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm doing an Angular course, in which I need to use `Http` to get data from the server. I have an `interface` defined named `IEvent`, and I have a service that's supposed to get the events:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class EventService {
  constructor(
    private _http: Http,
    @Inject(...) private _originUrl: string // This is listed in 'providers' in my module
  ) {}

  getEvents() {
    return this._http.get(`${this._originUrl}/api/events`)
      .map((response: Response) => <IEvent[]>response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError_);
  }

  handleError_(error: Response): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
  }
}
```

However, when I have this code, I see an error saying this:

```
  TS2322: Type 'Observable<string | IEvent[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IEvent[]>'.
Type 'string | IEvent[]' is not assignable to type 'IEvent[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IEvent[]'.
```

And if I reverse the order of `map` and `catch`:

```
return this._http.get(`${this._originUrl}/api/events`)
  .catch(this.handleError_)
  .map((response: Response) => <IEvent[]>response.json());
```

or, if I remove my type assertion for the JSON response:

```
return this._http.get(`${this._originUrl}/api/events`)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .catch(this.handleError_);
```

everything seems to be working fine. Can someone please explain what's happening here, and maybe provide some links so that I get more insight into this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, the `JSON` response's format is OK, and I don't think the reason is what you mentioned because I'm getting the error in VSCode when I'm writing the code, so it has nothing to do with the flow of the application (i.e., going into the `catch` block and not going into `map`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `handleError` method is declared as returning `Observable<string>`, so there are two possible paths in `getEvents`: one returns an `Observable<IEvent[]>` and the other an `Observable<string>`.

That's why you are seeing `Observable<string | IEvent[]>`.

Your error handler is not actually returning an observable of that type; it's returning an observable that always rethrows the an error, with the value of that error being a string. It's questionable whether throwing an error that is not an `Error` instance is good practice. I would not consider it to be.

The type specified for the observable returned by `handleError` refers to the type of the value that would be emitted for a `next` notification - not the type of the error. You could fix the problem be changing the signature to:

```ts
handleError_(error: Response): Observable<IEvent[]> {
  return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
}
```

or to:

```ts
handleError_(error: Response): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
}
```

And I would recommend throwing an `Error` rather than a string.

The problem does not occur without the type assertion, as the return type of `json()` is `any` - which is compatible with `string`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the return type of `handleError_` to be `Observable<IEvent>` (since I'm using the same error handler when getting a number of events or a single event), and it seems to be working. So, to follow your recommendation, if I want to throw an `Error`, should I do something like this: `return Observable.throw(new Error(error.statusText));`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yep. Although, you might want to do some more checking of `error` before accessing the `statusText`. For example, if there is no connectivity, the request will not have even made it to the server, so there will be no `statusText`, etc.